# Phonegap/Cordova 2.4 Inappbrowser and Ripple

Tags: cordova, ripple, inappbrowser

I'm using [Inappbrowser for Cordova 2.4](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser)  and have it working at last using XCode, the browser window pops up. My problem is we need to be able to test on Windows and don't really want to recompile using Phonegap Build every time we make a change due to the time it takes. PGB is also limited currently to Phonegap 2.3.

I'm using the Ripple Phonegap emulator in Google Chrome on Windows 7 to emulate the iOS app but am having no luck getting the Inappbrowser to work. So my questions are really

1) Is it possible to use Ripple to make use of Inappbrowser?

2) Is it possible to use Ripple to make use of any Phonegap api functions?

3) Am I limited to Phonegap (Cordova) 2.0.0 as this is the version showing as available in the latest version of Ripple.

4) Is there any other way to test Phonegap for iOS functionality without rebuilding/compiling?

Many Thanks,
Gazza

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can open a browser window with inAppBrowser, however the events will not work.  There is a feature request for this on the project:

https://github.com/blackberry/Ripple-UI/issues/701

Answer (score 0):

looked all over the web for sulotion and found nothing. Ripple does not suppor Inappbroswer plugin.